# Determining valid subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've been having problems getting this linear algebra topic. For instance, why are all polynomials of the form $p(t)=a+bt^2$, where $a, b \in \Bbb{R}$ a subspace of $P_n(t)$?

Let's say I have, for example, vectors $(5+6t^2)$ and $(6-6t^2)$. If I add them, the result would be $11$. So, wouldn't this violate the vector addition property? Cause $11$ is not in the form $a+bt^2$?

What about all polynomials of degree exactly $4$, with real coefficients?

It's probably a dumb question and I'm just thinking it all wrong but I would really appreciate it if someone could explain this to me.

Thanks!

Comment: $11$ equals $11+0t^2$ which is of the form $a+bt^2$.

Comment: polynomials of degree exactly 4 do not form a subspace, but polynomials of degree at most 4 do. Note that all polynomials of the form $p(t)=a+bt^2$ are the same as all polynomials of degree at most $2$. A basis for the latter subspace is $\{1,t^2\}$ and a linear combination with real coefficients $a,b$ ($0$ allowed as a coefficient) is exactly $a+bt^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $S=\{a+bt^2 \, | \, a,b \in \Bbb{R}\}$ consists of all linear combinations of $1$ and $t^2$ (also called as **span** of $1$ and $t^2$). For example, 
\begin{align*}
0 & =\color{red}{(0)}1+\color{red}{(0)}t^2\\
11 & =\color{red}{(11)}1+\color{red}{(0)}t^2\\
-7t^2 & =\color{red}{(0)}1+\color{red}{(-7)}t^2\\
\sqrt{2}+t^2 & =\color{red}{(\sqrt{2})}1+\color{red}{(1)}t^2
\end{align*}
are all members of set $S$. It can be shown easily that it is a subspace because if we pick $u(t)=a+bt^2$ and $v(t)=c+dt^2$, then 
$$u(t)+\lambda v(t)=\underbrace{(a+\lambda c)}_{\in \Bbb{R}}+\underbrace{(b+\lambda d)}_{\in \Bbb{R}}t^2 \in S.$$

---

When we say a degree $4$ polynomial, this means the term $t^4$ has a non-zero coefficient. So the set $T$ of degree $4$ polynomials is not a subspace because the zero vector (the zero polynomial) will not be in $T$ (as you may recall existence of zero vector is necessary for a set to be a subspace).